# Does Microsoft provide any web control for SharePoint Calendar view?

Tags: server

I want to display a SharePoint Calendar view in my  web part with some custom features. However, i cannot find any web control property about SharePoint calendar view.

For example, I want to append some div as a event to the SPCalendar day from my SQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

I have not implemented it before, but you should be able to accomplish this using List View Webpart.

For Example:

```
private void LoadCalendar()
{          
    string listName = "YourList";  
    string viewName = "Your View";

    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;  
    SPList list = web.Lists[listName];  
    SPView view = list.Views[viewName];  
    ListViewWebPart webPart  = new ListViewWebPart();
    webPart.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();   
    webPart.ViewType = ViewType.Calendar;  
    webPart.ViewGuid = list.Views[view].ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
    webPart.GetDesignTimeHtml();  
    this.calendarDiv.Controls.Add(webPart);
}
```

And on your user control / application page:

```
<div id="calendarDiv" runat="server">  
</div>
```

Comment: So, i have to create a splist for this calendar, right?

Comment: Indeed, assuming you want to display data from your SharePoint list.